# I need help understanding how this stepper motor circuit works

Tags: motor, stepper-motor, wiring, diagram

This is my first time working with stepper motors. The motor in question is a *Portescap* *55M048D1B* (source: http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/55M048D1B/403-1016-ND/417823). I am having trouble understanding the wiring diagram for the motor. Would anyone be kind enough to enlighten me on what role the inductor and transistors play in the circuit and how the circuit rotates the shaft. And how does a unipolar differ from a bipolar.

Comment: @Ignacio what I meant was what function do the four transistors perform

Comment: I am sure someone will add a better answer, but if you look at the wiring diagram, page 4, you will see a table explaining the order in which to turn on / off the transistors to 'step' the motor CW or CCW.

Answer (score 1):

The "inductors" are the windings in the motor itself. The transistors are supplied by whatever driver you decide to use.

[Bipolar vs. Unipolar](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/35292/11606)